# Subquery Returns More Than 1 Row Error No: 1242 on Homepage in Opencart 1.5.6

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am getting this error on home page while i am inserting any product from admin. but if i update the same product there was no error on home page.

My project is on opencart 1.5.6

> Warning: mysql_query(): Unable to save result set in
>   /home4/hathberr/public_html/sdfabrics.com/system/database/mysql.php on
>   line 22Notice: Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Error No: 1242

`SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, 
(SELECT price FROM oc_product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1)
 AS discount, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special,
(SELECT points FROM oc_product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '1') AS reward,
 (SELECT ss.name FROM oc_stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '1') AS stock_status,
 (SELECT wcd.unit FROM oc_weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '1') AS weight_class, 
(SELECT lcd.unit FROM oc_length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '1') AS length_class,
 (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM oc_review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM oc_review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM oc_product p 
LEFT JOIN 
oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
 LEFT JOIN 
oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
 LEFT JOIN oc_manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '166' AND pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0'`

in /home4/hathberr/public_html/sdfabrics.com/system/database/mysql.php on line 50

this query is on catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 14

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");
```

I have tried my time to resolve this but failed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to phpmyadmin>yourdatabase
and check all the tables.
remove unwanted tables.
check database engine and charset. if any table has different then set them to default charset and DB esngine.

and it's done. i hv solved my problm. try it will help u in opencart.

Answer (score 0):

Sub-query cannot return more than one row. Some of your sub-query might return more than one row. You have to set `limit 1` to all your sub-query.

Comment: i have already added limit 1 to all sub query but nothing change.